# On the $0$ representation of massive multiplets

Tags: representation-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra

So my doubt involves the massive multiplet of $\mathcal{N}=2$. I am not being able to deduce what particles does the states represents. For example,

The $\mathcal{N}=2$ massive short hypermultiplet $s=0$ is given by

$$(2 \times (-1/2), 4 \times 0, 2 \times (1/2))$$

Consisting of a $1$ Dirac fermion, and two massive complex scalars

The $\mathcal{N}=2$ massive short vector multiplet $s=1/2$ is given by

$$(-1, 2 \times (-1/2), 2 \times (0), 2 \times (1/2), 1 )$$

Consisting of one massive vector, one masive Dirac fermion and one massive real scalar.

The point is, while i can understand intuitivelly that $1,-1$ states represents a vector particle, and $(2 \times (-1/2), 2 \times (1/2))$ represent a Dirac Fermion, why does $2 \times (0)$ represents only one massive real scalar, and not two massive real scalar?

Ok, we could talk about degree of freedom, but this is not how we deduce which particle it represents, i guess.

Comment: A massive real vector has three, not two polarization states, unlike the massless one. So one of the two helicity 0 states is part of the vector, and there is only one left.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh! Thank you